# What is the correct folder location for a dissector lua as plugin for wireshark?

Tags: plugins, lua

I have a `lua dissector` (`xxx.lua`) which I normally run on windows under `C:\Program Files\Wireshark\plugins\2.2.4`

I tried to copy this in Ubuntu 14.04 following various recommendations found online without success.

Can I use the same `lua dissector` in Uubuntu?

If so, what is the exact location where `Wireshark` loads dissectors?

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for the same thing..

User plugins should be here:

```
~/.local/lib/wireshark/plugins
```

Source: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChPluginFolders.html